# how to replace specfic value from the option tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i want to append the text box values in the dropdown list when user can change the text box value that time the existing value should be replaced to changed value in the option tag without selected how i can do this

```
   var valuedata
   $('.txtbox1').click(function (){
       valuedata = $(this).val();
   });
   $('.txtbox1').focusout(function (){
        var data = $(this).val();
        if ($('.ddl [value ="' + valuedata + '"]').val() == valuedata) {
            alert(valuedata);    
            $('.ddl').append($("<option value=" + data + " ></option>").html(data).val(data));
        }
        else {
            $(".ddl [value='" + valuedata + "']").val(data);
        }
   });
```

Comment: Sorry friend i new for this job markup means

Comment: @Dinesh: How many options are there in the select? will there be always only one option?

Comment: No i will auto generate four text box so it append all 4 textbox value if any one text value is change i need to update in dropdown please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('select option:contains("old_text")').text('new_text');
```

To check for option is appended or not :

```
$("select option").each(function(i,obj){
    if($(obj).text() == "your_text"){
        console.log("yes");
    }
})
```

Comment: hi frnd first i want to check the old value is already append or not pls help me

Comment: @Dinesh I have edited my answer for checking option is present or not please check is that what you want

Comment: Sorry friend its also not working it not showing any response

Comment: provide fiddle demo so i will get idea what you need exactly

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/c2Ry8/ see this its append textbox values but i need append new textbox value and replace the old text box value

Comment: first time i will dinesh its append then second time i will type dina its also append its have two values now but i want only latest value

Comment: not like i want replace the old value for example first i will type dinesh in text box next time i type dina ok in dropdown list i need only dina option that it

Comment: Ya friend its support for single text box if mutple textbox is not support

Comment: Yes @Dinesh that you need to do, if you got correct answer then accept   it

Comment: i m not getting the answer see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866467/the-text-box-values-are-auto-append-and-replaced-in-dropdown-list-using-jqeury

Comment: sorry but i answered for this question not the above given dear.

Comment: Ok did u know any other forums jquery because i having less time to submit this module in my company please help me

Comment: yes i will solve above question also but you should accept this answer for this question @Dinesh.

Answer (score 0):

There are spaces before [value `$(".ddl [value='" + valuedata + "']").val(data);` which might be problem. So, remove that space:

```
$(".ddl[value='" + valuedata + "']").val(data);
```

---

Use html instead of append like this:

```
$('.ddl').html($("<option value=" + data + " ></option>")
```

Comment: did you remove that spaces?

Comment: ya i removed it but its doesnot goto else condition

Comment: if you show in the fiddle we could help you like in this http://jsfiddle.net/WDzHw/ just add the html code in this fiddle

Comment: yes friend its only append the values its not replace the value

Comment: ya its append the textbox value in dropdrown if change the text in textbox is not updated

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/c2Ry8/

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.txtbox1').focusout(function (){
            var data = $(this).val();
            $('.ddl').append("<option value=" + data + " >"+data+"</option>");
            });
    });
```

Comment: first i having problem in if condition my dear friend then only i need to check append method

Comment: yes friend its appending values but its doesnot replace the old value