# the text box values are auto append and replaced in dropdown list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

hi friends if 4 text box is created based on below code then while text box focus out then that text box value are append in dropdown list its working fine but while user can change the text box value i need to replace old textbox value to new value how can i do this please help me friends

My text box Creation and dropdown creation

```
      <% for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt16(Model.NumGroups); i++)
           { %>
       <tr>
       <td>
           <%: Html.Label("Group" + (i+1).ToString()) %><br />
           <%: Html.TextBox("GroupName", null , new { id= i, @class = "GroupName" })%>
       </td>
       </tr>
       <%} %>
       <% for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt16(Model.NumGroups); i++)
           { %>
       <tr>
       <td>
           <select classname = "GroupSelect">
           <option></option></select>
       </td>
       </tr>
       <%} %>
```

My jquery

```
   $('.GroupName').focusout(function () {
        var data = $(this).val();
        var get = $(this).attr('id');            
        $('GroupSelect option')[parseInt(get + 1)].text = data;
    });
```

Comment: How will you come to know which value of dropdown is edited by user??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"while user can change the text box value i need to replace old textbox value"

try using onkeyup or onblur.

Example:

```
<%: Html.TextBox("GroupName", null , new { id= i, @class = "GroupName", onkeyup="myonkeyup()" })%>

<script>
 function myonkeyup()
 {
  //get current value & replace
 }
</script>
```